# Publish posts only after the condition is met

Tags: posts, publish

I want to add 2 posts daily, so when the first post is published it should not be published unless and until the 2nd post is published. I am confused on how to do this.

I have searched about wp_publish_post() function but this will not help, is there any way to do this ?

I know there is no code or anything, because I am confused and did not find anything regarding this. I only need some help on how to start, rest I can do.

Answer (score 1):

## Setup cron job

You want to do some action (i.e. publishing a post) periodically, so first you need to schedule a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Cron jobs are actions, that are fired periodically at some sort of a time interval.

You can either use (non-perfect) [Wordpress Cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) or [replace it with a real cron job on your hosting](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/real-cron-job/).

## In cron action, publish one of the post with status `draft`

Inside the cron job, you can query for 1 post with the `post_status === 'draft'`. If one is found, change its `post_status` to `publish` with [`wp_update_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post).